# Can't stop scroll event from firing too many times

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-pagination

So I have been reading up on this problem and have seen quite a lot of different solutions. At the moment my code looks like this:

I am using this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

```
// Bind throttled scroll event to load new items when page is scrolled to the bottom.
$(window).data('loading', false).scroll($.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad));

Olemas.ScrollLoad = function()  {
  if ($(window).data('loading') == true) return;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
      if (Olemas.NextPage <= Olemas.MaxPage) {
          $(window).unbind('scroll'); // I have tried unbinding the event to stop it from launching
          Olemas.LoadMoreItems(Olemas.DivToUpdate); // load the new items
          $(window).data('loading', false).scroll($.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad)); // rebind scroll event.
      }

  }
};
```

The problem is that even though the event is firing once every 800 ms. When I scroll to the bottom fast, the scroll event is firing too many times and the pages are loaded all wrong.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()))
```

This statement should not pass after my items are loaded to the page, but it still passes a few times before it realizes the page height has changed. Is it possible that the height attributes are not updated quickly enough or the scroll events are already loaded into the DOM somehow?

What can I do to stop the scroll event from firing after the LoadMoreItems function has expanded the page.

EDIT.

So in this function, the alerts are ran 2 times and then an alert in the LoadMoreItems ajax success.

```
Olemas.ScrollLoad = function()  {
/// <summary>
/// Loads more items when scrolled to the bottom.
/// </summary>
if ($(window).data('loading') == true) return;
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
    if (Olemas.NextPage <= Olemas.MaxPage) {
        alert(Olemas.NextPage); // This runs 2 times, before the LoadMoreItems changes the NextPage value
        $(window).off('scroll', $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad));

        Olemas.LoadMoreItems(Olemas.DivToUpdate);
        $(window).data('loading', false).on('scroll', $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad)); // rebind scroll event.
    }

}
};

Olemas.LoadMoreItems = function () {
  $(window).data('loading', true);
  $.ajax({
      url: Olemas.ActionLink,
      data: { "page": Olemas.NextPage, "facId": Olemas.FacultyId },
      success: function (data) {
          $(".loadingImage").hide();
          $(data).appendTo(Olemas.DivToUpdate);
          alert("Done") // This is run after the previous alerts have fired 2 times.
          Olemas.NextPage++;
          Olemas.CheckPages();
      }
  });
  return false;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so my problem was the following:

```
// Bind throttled scroll event to load new items when page is scrolled to the bottom.
$(window).data('loading', false).scroll($.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad));

Olemas.ScrollLoad = function()  {
  if ($(window).data('loading') == true) return;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
   if (Olemas.NextPage <= Olemas.MaxPage) {
      $(window).unbind('scroll'); // I have tried unbinding the event to stop it from launching
      Olemas.LoadMoreItems(Olemas.DivToUpdate); // load the new items
      $(window).data('loading', false).scroll($.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad)); // rebind scroll event.
      //The LoadMoreItems was an AJAX method and the rebinding was made before the ajax call had succeeded. 
      //That is why it fired the scroll event too many times.
  }

}
};
```

I solved it, by moving the loading boolean check into the LoadMoreItems method, that way the method had to finish before the scroll was rebinded.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using `on()` / `off()` :

```
$(window).data('loading', false).on('scroll', doScroll);

Olemas.ScrollLoad = function() {
    if ($(window).data('loading') == true) return;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        if (Olemas.NextPage <= Olemas.MaxPage) {
            $(window).off('scroll', doScroll);
            Olemas.LoadMoreItems(Olemas.DivToUpdate); // load the new items
            $(window).data('loading', false).on('scroll', doScroll);
        }
    }
};

function doScroll() {
    $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad);
}​
```

**EDIT:**

You CAN NOT do :

```
$(window).on('scroll', $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad));
```

It has to be :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad));
});
```

or simply:

```
$(window).on('scroll', doScroll);

function doScroll() {
    $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad);
}​
```

to call a seperate function !

The last option with a seperate function makes it easier to just unbind that function with `off()`, or you can unbind any function by doing :

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I think it has led me closer to the answer. I placed an alert(Olemas.NextPage) into the ScrollLoad function after the if (Olemas.NextPage <= ..) check and before the LoadMoreItems function. If I scroll fast the alert fires 2 times and then the LoadMoreItems function is ran that changes the NextPage value. I have updated my first post

Comment: That's beacause you are calling the `$.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad)` function twice, and not attaching it to anything. When passing a function to a handler you cant use parenthesis and options, then you'll need a seperate function call, hence the seperate function `doScroll` in my example, which was kind of the most important thing in that answer ?

Comment: If I use `$(window).on('scroll', function () { $.throttle(800, Olemas.ScrollLoad); });` The scroll event never fires.

Comment: It all depends on what element is actually being scrolled, is it the window, the body, or some other element. You'll have to bind to the element that is being scrolled, and there are some browser inconsistencies as well. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LF5DD/) to see the event fire...

Comment: I don't understand how that explains why the ScrollLoad method doesn't work without parenthesis. Do I have to change the function somehow? Javascript functions give me a headache.

Comment: Whenever you write a function name with the parenthesis you execute the function immediately. What you want is to execute the function on every scroll event, and then you'll have to write the functions name without the parenthesis or inside another function call, like above. To execute something on scroll, you have to figure out what element is actually being scrolled, most of the time it's the window or document, but for the latter IE and opera will instead use the document.documentElement, or in other words the html tag, so there are incosistencies.

Comment: You need to check that the `.on('scroll', function() {...})` is being executed when doing the scrolling, and to do that you write something to the console to see that the function actually fires etc.

Comment: I added the solution. The code in my first post was almost correct. It was the loading check that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution with timestamps and an interval. The interval is required to fire the event one last time after the scroll function is completed. I set the delay to 50 for performance reasons. This example fires the function every 2 seconds, have fun customizing.

```
    var interval, timestamp = Date.now(),

    scrollFunction = function() {
        console.log('fire');
    },

    scrollHandler = function() {
        if(!interval) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                if((Date.now() - timestamp) > 2000) {
                    timestamp = Date.now();
                    scrollFunction();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = undefined;
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    }

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
scrollHandler();
```